# Ubuntu 14.04 won't download apps?

Tags: wireless, 14.04, software-center

I have replaced Windows 7 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.The problem is I can't download any apps from software center. I click on the app and it said "Available from the 'universe' source". I click the button that said "use this source". All it said was "Updating  Cache Querying software sources" but nothing happens. On top of that, I can't use the web browser either. It said "Sever not found" but my wifi connection is great. I don't understand.

Comment: Do you have any internet connectivity? Can you ping your gateway? can yo ping www.google.com?

Comment: I can't get on the internet at all. It won't display any web page. I'm not sure how to ping.

Comment: So your problem is probably that you don't have internet access which is needed to download apps. Open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t). and add to you question the outputs of `ifconfig` and `ping google.com`

Comment: Alright, I have pinged it and it said "ping: unknown host google.com"

Comment: Your problem is "No internet connection, but connection to LAN is working". which usually indicates a misconfiguration in your network settings. You should head to Google with this new direction or ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

My wireless card was not up to date, it was unsupported. I replaced the card and everything works fine. If anyone else has a similar problem, I recommend updating your drivers manually. Thanks to all the people who helped me! :D